# Set date on embedded linux with limited busybox (no ntp)

Tags: date, wget, busybox

I am trying to automatically set a date after boot on an embedded linux  with busybox ( I don't have a RTC).
I also don't have `ntp` command in busybox, nor curl. My `wget` is very limited too, and I can't seem to get headers with it.

I have seen multiple ways that use `curl` or `wget` that parse the header of google.com to get the current date.

But my `wget` command doesn't support `--server-response` option:

```
BusyBox v1.21.0 (2014-11-25 08:52:04 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [-s|--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

        -s      Spider mode - only check file existence
        -c      Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q      Quiet
        -P DIR  Save to DIR (default .)
        -T SEC  Network read timeout is SEC seconds
        -O FILE Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
        -U STR  Use STR for User-Agent header
        -Y      Use proxy ('on' or 'off')
```

I this solution somewhere, but I only have POSIX shell, not bash, so it doesn't work (`can't create /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80: nonexistent directory`):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80
cat mypostfile >&5
cat <&5 # reply
```

Any ideas how I can still retrieve the current date from somewhere so I can set my system clock with my busybox?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a proxy at localhost port 8000,
if your busybox has telnet, you can try

```
( echo 'HEAD http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.0'
  echo
  sleep 2 ) |
busybox telnet localhost 8000 |
grep 'Date:'
```

where the sleep command is approximate and stops telnet closing the connection too soon.

I'm surprised this still works without redirecting to https, which, for example, `busybox wget` does not support. You would still get the date on the redirection though.

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm behind a proxy I'd need to  talk to the proxy first. So when I try `telnet proxy.ip port`, then enter `HEAD http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1` and then hit enter twice it prints out the header. But I dont know how to put this in a bash script. Could you give me a hint there?

Comment: I don't think much changes. I've edited the answer for a simple proxy at localhost. You probably still only need the single extra `echo` on its own to send a blank line after header. If this doesn't flush the data through you can add more `echo` commands.